# Why is st_buffer function not creating an R object that correctly displays in mapview?

Tags: r, sf, mapview

Trying to get st_buffer function to display a buffer within mapview.  Got it to work, but I had to first perform a transform (I doubt this is necessary).  Looking for a more straightforward way to do this.

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)

data("breweries")

test_coords <- st_geometry(breweries[1:2,])

# This code doesn't work. Not sure why.
# buff_test_coords <- st_buffer(test_coords, dist = 10000)
# mapview(test_coords) + mapview(buff_test_coords)

# This code words. Not sure what's special about transforming to 3488
sf_test_coords <- test_coords %>% st_transform(3488)
sf_buff_test_coords <- st_buffer(sf_test_coords, 10000)
sf_buff_test_coords2 <- st_transform(sf_buff_test_coords, 4326)
mapview(test_coords) + mapview(sf_buff_test_coords2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the warning messages generated by the code you say didnt work?

```
> test_coords <- st_geometry(breweries[1:2,])
> buff_test_coords <- st_buffer(test_coords, dist = 10000)
dist is assumed to be in decimal degrees (arc_degrees).
Warning message:
In st_buffer.sfc(test_coords, dist = 10000) :
  st_buffer does not correctly buffer longitude/latitude data
```

Specifically `dist is assumed to be in decimal degrees (arc_degrees).`. You are doing a buffer that is **10000 degrees** (and a sphere has only 360 all the way round.

The reason CRS 3488 works is because it is a system with metres as its coordinates, not degrees lat-long like `breweries` has:

```
> st_crs(sf_test_coords)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 3488 
  proj4string: "+proj=aea +lat_1=34 +lat_2=40.5
                +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-120 +x_0=0 +y_0=-4000000
                +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
                +units=m +no_defs"
```

I don't know where you picked 3488 out of, but because of the problems of flattening a sphere onto a flat map, you need to make sure that the coordinate system you choose for a buffer operation is appropriate to the geographic location of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60899504/7877917

Well, the warning is pretty clear, buffering doesn't work well for non-projected data.

```r
#> Warning in st_buffer.sfc(test_coords, dist = 2): st_buffer does not correctly
#> buffer longitude/latitude data
#> dist is assumed to be in decimal degrees (arc_degrees).
```

Your data shows `proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"` so you either project it or change the approach. On top of that, you tried to project lonlat (-180,180 degrees) by 10000, meaning 10000 degrees. So that is a non-sense buffer, buffering works on the same units of the projection.

You have here two approaches without projecting:

- Buffering by 2 degrees, it works but the buffer is quite strange.
- Another option is just to plot two times the same point, but not passing it to `POLYGON`, that is what the buffer does. Just plot it the second time with a bigger `cex`.

```r
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(mapview)
#> Warning: package 'mapview' was built under R version 3.5.3

data("breweries")

test_coords <- st_geometry(breweries[1:2,])
st_crs(test_coords)
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   EPSG: 4326 
#>   proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
buff_test_coords <- st_buffer(test_coords, dist = 2)
#> Warning in st_buffer.sfc(test_coords, dist = 2): st_buffer does not correctly
#> buffer longitude/latitude data
#> dist is assumed to be in decimal degrees (arc_degrees).

#Buffering non-projected coords
mapview(test_coords) + mapview(buff_test_coords)
```

[image]

```r
#Plotting the same points with a bigger cex
mapview(test_coords) + mapview(test_coords, cex=100, col.regions ="red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>